# How to create user without SSH access on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, user

I want to create a user to auto-login without a password. However, I don't want someone to be able to SSH as that user since the user will not have a password. How can I create a user without a password and no SSH access? I am running Raspbian.

Comment: Are you planning to enable auto-login through X, or were you thinking of playing with the pam config to make it work from terminals etc?

Comment: Actually, auto-login without X (or before X).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create the user like normal and setup the auto login how you want it,
Then add the user to DenyUsers in /etc/ssh/sshd_config
e.g.
`DenyUser autologinuser`
Restart ssh after you update the config file.

Reference : http://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config